# "ECHO was unexpected at this time" During FOR/IF statement

Tags: batch-file, scripting, echo, batch-processing

Below is a snippet of code which is throwing an "ECHO was unexpected at this time" error:

```
SET SN_List_Filename=SN_LIST_%DATE:/=%.txt
SET SN_List_Filename_Temp=%SN_List_Filename%.temp

ECHO Date: %DATE:~0,2%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~-4% > %SN_List_Filename_Temp%
ECHO SN List: >> %SN_List_Filename_Temp%
ECHO. >> %SN_List_Filename_Temp%

IF NOT EXIST %SN_List_Filename% (
    ECHO. > %SN_List_Filename%
) ELSE (

    SET SN_List=%serial%
    SET index=0
    SET snCount=1

    FOR /f "tokens=* skip=5" %%a IN (%SN_List_Filename%) DO (

        SET SN_List=!SN_List!;%%a   
        FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%b IN ("%SN_List%") DO (
            IF %%a==%%b (
                ECHO %%b>> %SN_List_Filename_Temp%
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The error is thrown if the "%%a==%%b" comparison is satisfied.

*N.B. enabledelayedexpansion is set and ECHO is set to off.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but: `%%b`==`%SN_List%`, `%SN_List%` == `%serial%;%%a` so, `%%b` can not be equal to `%%a` unless `%serial%` is empty.

Comment: @MCND yes, I think you're missing the SET command just before the loop, i.e. "SET SN_List=!SN_List!;%%a", as each serial number (a) is appended to "SN_List". Also note that the FOR loop over "SN_List" tokenises the string (with ";" as the delimiter), thus SN_List is not equal to b (as b is a single token of SN_List).

Comment: No, the `for /f` with `tokens=*` does not tokenize the string, only removes leading delimiters. And in the case of tokenization (ex. `tokens=1-10`), what it does not do is to iterate over the list of tokens. Only one pass is done over the string, with each token inside a separate replaceable parameter.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding about `FOR /F` and `tokens=*`. I've tried the following: `FOR /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%i IN ("aa;bb;cc;dd;ee") DO @echo %%i` but it doesn't parse the string `"aa;bb;cc;dd;ee"`. Is it what you expect to happen in your code ?

Comment: I think the problem is that the first line sets `%SN_List_Filename%` to a value including a space; but you don't have the variable quoted on the `if not exist` line.

Comment: I'd use `IF "%%a"=="%%b" (`. However, have got `'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` message, so need to use `echo(` instead. What about serial number format? Might contain spaces, `!` or other _'unusual'_ characters?